# R Get complement of small matrix in larger matrix

Tags: r

I have a n×2 matrix `A` and and m×2 matrix `B` with m<n. I want to find the complement of `B` in `A`, i.e. all rows from `A` that are not in `B`. How would I do that in base r?

`setdiff` does not work as it does not respect the matrix structure. `rbind`+`duplicate` does also not work since there may be rows in `B` that are not in `A` at all.

Answer (score 0):

We can `paste` the values row-wise and check if they are present in `B` using `%in%` :

```
A[!paste(A[, 1], A[, 2], sep = '-') %in% paste(B[, 1], B[, 2], sep = '-'),]
```

---

Using reproducible data :

```
A <- matrix(1:16, ncol = 2)
B <- matrix(c(2, 10, 1, 2, 5, 13, 6, 14, 8, 16), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
A
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    9
#[2,]    2   10
#[3,]    3   11
#[4,]    4   12
#[5,]    5   13
#[6,]    6   14
#[7,]    7   15
#[8,]    8   16

B
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2   10
#[2,]    1    2
#[3,]    5   13
#[4,]    6   14
#[5,]    8   16

A[!paste(A[, 1], A[, 2], sep = '-') %in% paste(B[, 1], B[, 2], sep = '-'),]

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    9
#[2,]    3   11
#[3,]    4   12
#[4,]    7   15
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work. changing the 8,1 element of A to, say, 2 does not change the result but the row `2 16` is not contained in B.

Comment: @SydAmerikaner Updated the answer.